# how to redirect from jsp of one portlet to jsp of another portlet inside liferay module project in liferay 7

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-7

I have created two liferay module project. one is "portlet-demo1" and second is "portlet-demo2"

Now I need to navigate from view.jsp of "portlet-demo1" to view.jsp of "portlet-demo2"

**NOTE : Here both portlet is in separate page.**

Now I need to navigate from one portlet jsp to another portlet jsp file.

how to do this using liferay 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you separate the two portlets into two different modules, you should treat the JSPs of the other module as an implementation detail, e.g. you can't reach it (even if there'd be a way to reach them).

If the two portlets are tightly coupled and should share their implementation details, you can easily deploy them as a single module. This signals to anybody maintaining them, that they're required to be deployed together. Otherwise you might end up with one portlet being incomplete because the other portlet updated and nobody was aware that a JSP was used by some external component.

It's no problem to package two portlets in a single module. Go with that technique.

Comment: Thanks Olaf Kock,

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, just click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer - that also signals others that you don't need another answer to this question, or that this answer might answer their identical question as well.